# $f(a) = \frac{a^6}{8} - \int\int~\frac{x^2y^2}{e^{(x^2 + y^2)}} ~dy~dx$ Find $a$ such that $f(a)$ is minimum.

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, multiple-integral

Let $ D_a =$ {$~(x,y) ; x^2 + y^2 \leq a~$} circule .

the double integral is on $D_a$

$f(a) = \frac{a^6}{8} - \int\int~\frac{x^2y^2}{e^{(x^2 + y^2)}} ~dy~dx$

**Find $a$ such that $f(a)$ is minimum.**

**assure that is is indeed the minimum**

$(1)~$Can one calculate the integral  ?

**What I did :**

going to polar coordinates :

$f(a) = \frac{a^6}{8} -\frac{\pi}{4}\int_{0}^{a} r^5e^{(-r^4)}~dr$

now $f'(a) = \frac{6a^5}{8} - \frac{\pi}{4}a^5e^{-a^4}$ Fundumental theorem of calc.

and i get

$a_{\min} = \ln(\frac{\pi}{3}~)^{\tfrac{1}{4}}$

The problem is I dont know how to find the minimum since I don't know how to calculate the integral.

Comment: Why do you need to calculate the integral for? Didn't you just solve the problem? find $a_{\rm min}$?

Comment: @caverac they also said "assure that it is indeed the minumum " in brackets

Comment: @caverac also i am not sure that i solved it right

Comment: Then compute $f''(a)$. The sign would determine the minimality/maximality.

Comment: @xbh yes but how do i find the minmum

Comment: @xbh i.e calculate the double integral

Comment: Maybe very hard… I wonder if it is solvable…

Answer (score 1):

You already have it. Now just differentiate once more:

$$f''(a)=\frac{15}4a^4-\frac{5\pi}4a^4e^{-a^4}+4a^8\pi e^{-a^4}\implies$$

$$f''\left(\log\left(\frac\pi3\right)^{1/4}\right)=\frac{15}4\,\log\frac\pi3-\frac{5\pi}4\,\log\frac\pi3\cdot\frac\pi3+8\,\log\frac\pi3\cdot\pi\cdot\frac\pi3=$$

$$=\log\frac\pi3\left[\frac{15}4-\frac{5\pi^2}{12}+\frac{8\pi^2}3\right]=\left[\frac{15}4+\frac{9\pi^2}4\right]\log\frac\pi3>0$$

and thus that point indeed is a minimum...Of course, it is possible to shorten the above. Up to you.

Comment: yes i did that to know that its minmum but how  do I find the minmum itself , ie how to calculate the integral

Comment: @RaziAwad I don't understand your question: the minimum **itself** is $\;\frac14\log\frac\pi3\;$ , as you wrote...! What else? Why do you want to solve the integral for??

Comment: the value of $f(a_{min})$ , i dont know how to calculate it

Comment: @RaziAwad But you wrote you were only asked to find $\;a\;$ ...and you did.

Comment: @RaziAwad Minimum is the value of the function. Argmin is the value of the argument for which the function attains its minimum. You need to find the argmin but not the minimum. $e^{-r^4}$ in the integrand should be $e^{-r^2}$, so $a_{\text {min}} = \ln^{1/2}(\pi/3)$ (I assume $D_a$ is $x^2 + y^2 < a^2$, not $x^2 + y^2 < a$).